# SQL - MERGE INTO - from XML with children

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm trying to write a SQL script to import data from an XML. In the database, I prepared 2 tables:
* CodeGroup with the following fields: Code / Description

- CodeValue with the following fields: Code / Description / CodeGroupId (FK - int)
  => 1 CodeGroup have many CodeValue

Here's a part of the XML:

```
<MASTERDATA plant="SXB">
    <CODEGROUPS>
        <CODEGROUPC><CODEGROUP>ANODE</CODEGROUP><CODEGROUPX>Condition of anodes</CODEGROUPX>
            <CODEVALUES>
              <CODEVALUEC><CODEVALUE>02AD</CODEVALUE><CODEVALUEX>2-Minor Depletion / Damage</CODEVALUEX></CODEVALUEC>
              <CODEVALUEC><CODEVALUE>03AD</CODEVALUE><CODEVALUEX>3-Major Depletion / Plan to refurbish</CODEVALUEX></CODEVALUEC>
            </CODEVALUES>
        </CODEGROUPC>
        <CODEGROUPC><CODEGROUP>AUTO</CODEGROUP><CODEGROUPX>Measurement method</CODEGROUPX>
            <CODEVALUES>
              <CODEVALUEC><CODEVALUE>00ND</CODEVALUE><CODEVALUEX>0-Inspection Not Done/not inspectable</CODEVALUEX></CODEVALUEC>
              <CODEVALUEC><CODEVALUE>01AU</CODEVALUE><CODEVALUEX>Automatic</CODEVALUEX></CODEVALUEC>
              <CODEVALUEC><CODEVALUE>01MA</CODEVALUE><CODEVALUEX>Manual</CODEVALUEX></CODEVALUEC>
            </CODEVALUES>
        </CODEGROUPC>
      </CODEGROUPS>
</MASTERDATA>
```

I don't know if it's possible to write in a single MERGE INTO statement the ability to insert the values in CodeGroup and in CodeValue:

```
MERGE INTO [dbo].[CodeGroup] AS TARGET
USING
(
SELECT DISTINCT
    d.x.value('../../@plant[1]', 'nvarchar(15)') as PlantId,
    d.x.value('INGRP[1]', 'nchar(3)') as Code,
    d.x.value('INGRPX[1]', 'nvarchar(20)') as Name
FROM @data.nodes('/MASTERDATA/CODEGROUPS/CODEGROUPC')as d(x)
)
AS SOURCE ON (SOURCE.Code= TARGET.Code
AND SOURCE.PlantId = TARGET.PlantId)
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET SOURCE.Name= TARGET.Name
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT (PlantId, Code, Name)
         VALUES (SOURCE.PlantId, SOURCE.Code, SOURCE.Name)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND (TARGET.PlantId in (SELECT PlantId FROM #TempTable))
    THEN DELETE;
```

That's what I prepared but I didn't find out how to and the "children" (CodeValue of a CodeGroup)
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting two different tables. This cannot be done in a single statement.

Try this code:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<MASTERDATA plant="SXB">
    <CODEGROUPS>
        <CODEGROUPC><CODEGROUP>ANODE</CODEGROUP><CODEGROUPX>Condition of anodes</CODEGROUPX>
            <CODEVALUES>
              <CODEVALUEC><CODEVALUE>02AD</CODEVALUE><CODEVALUEX>2-Minor Depletion / Damage</CODEVALUEX></CODEVALUEC>
              <CODEVALUEC><CODEVALUE>03AD</CODEVALUE><CODEVALUEX>3-Major Depletion / Plan to refurbish</CODEVALUEX></CODEVALUEC>
            </CODEVALUES>
        </CODEGROUPC>
        <CODEGROUPC><CODEGROUP>AUTO</CODEGROUP><CODEGROUPX>Measurement method</CODEGROUPX>
            <CODEVALUES>
              <CODEVALUEC><CODEVALUE>00ND</CODEVALUE><CODEVALUEX>0-Inspection Not Done/not inspectable</CODEVALUEX></CODEVALUEC>
              <CODEVALUEC><CODEVALUE>01AU</CODEVALUE><CODEVALUEX>Automatic</CODEVALUEX></CODEVALUEC>
              <CODEVALUEC><CODEVALUE>01MA</CODEVALUE><CODEVALUEX>Manual</CODEVALUEX></CODEVALUEC>
            </CODEVALUES>
        </CODEGROUPC>
      </CODEGROUPS>
</MASTERDATA>';

SELECT @xml.value('(/MASTERDATA/@plant)[1]','varchar(100)') AS Masterdata_plant
      ,cGr.value('(CODEGROUP/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS CodeGroup
      ,cGr.value('(CODEGROUPX/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS CodeGroupX
      ,cVl.value('(CODEVALUE/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS CodeValue
      ,cVl.value('(CODEVALUEX/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS CodeValueX
INTO #tmpXmlData
FROM @xml.nodes('/MASTERDATA/CODEGROUPS/CODEGROUPC') A(cGr)
OUTER APPLY cGr.nodes('CODEVALUES/CODEVALUEC') B(cVl);

SELECT * FROM #tmpXmlData;
```

Use the result you find in `#tmpXmlData` to run `MERGE` statements against both tables separately.

Comment: May I ask you what kind of MERGE statements are you thinking ? :) Because the first MERGE I was thinking is to insert elements in COdeValue and then the second MERGE to insert in parent table : CodeGroup ? Don't forget the primary keys of both tables are "int" type

Comment: @moueidat No idea what you need... You are describing two tables `Code` and `CodeGroup` and it needs almost magic abilities to reckon, that there are INT-PKs involved. While your code is targeting a table `PlannerGroup`... Are the codes in `CodeGroup` (like `ANODE`) and in `Code` (like `02AD`) unique in their context? Don't you need a `m:n` relation with a third table in between? Try to set up a reduced but running *stand-alone* example and state the expected output.

Comment: Oops sorry I didn't mean PLannerGroup but CodeGroup indeed :p

Comment: @moueidat You might use my approach, add a `CodeValueID` and a `CodeGroupID` to the table and set the existing IDs wherever you find one. The rest should be easy...

Answer (score 0):

Shnugo through out the challenge, when he said it was impossible to do this in one `MERGE` statement.  And he was right, I think.  However, it got me thinking because I have used the `OUTPUT` clause many times to solve this type of problem, which I think is a MASTER - DETAIL merge, when the key of the master table is not the business key and is an `IDENTITY()` or `NEWID()`.

What is the most efficient way of doing what you want to do?  Shnugo gave you a partial solution, so I have enhanced it (thanks and credit to Shnugo) to give you what you want but it uses an `INSERT` into temp table, then two `MERGE` statements.  One for the master and one for the detail table.

The first MERGE uses a trick that allows you to retrieve the new IDENTITY field of the new rows, so that you don't have to join back to the master table by the business keys when doing the detail table.  I hope this helps.

Here's my code:

Assumptions:

I have put NOT NULLs on several fields.
I have put a CASCADE DELETE on the foreign key reference.

```
create table dbo.CodeGroup (
    CodeGroupId int identity(1,1) primary key,
    Masterdata_plant varchar(100) not null,
    Code varchar(100) not null,
    Description varchar(100) not null

    )
go
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CodeGroup] ON dbo.CodeGroup
(
    [Masterdata_plant] ASC,
    [Code] ASC
)
go
create table dbo.CodeValue 
(
    Code varchar(100) not null,
    CodeGroupId int not null,
    Description varchar(100) not null,
     CONSTRAINT PK_CodeValue PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    Code ASC,
    CodeGroupId ASC
)
    )
go
ALTER TABLE dbo.CodeValue  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_CodeValue_CodeGroup FOREIGN KEY(CodeGroupId)
REFERENCES dbo.CodeGroup (CodeGroupId)
ON DELETE CASCADE
go
ALTER TABLE dbo.CodeValue CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_CodeValue_CodeGroup
go
delete from dbo.CodeGroup
go
delete from dbo.CodeValue
go

DECLARE @data XML=
'<MASTERDATA plant="SXB">
    <CODEGROUPS>
        <CODEGROUPC><CODEGROUP>ANODE</CODEGROUP><CODEGROUPX>Condition of anodes</CODEGROUPX>
            <CODEVALUES>
              <CODEVALUEC><CODEVALUE>02AD</CODEVALUE><CODEVALUEX>2-Minor Depletion / Damage</CODEVALUEX></CODEVALUEC>
              <CODEVALUEC><CODEVALUE>03AD</CODEVALUE><CODEVALUEX>3-Major Depletion / Plan to refurbish</CODEVALUEX></CODEVALUEC>
            </CODEVALUES>
        </CODEGROUPC>
        <CODEGROUPC><CODEGROUP>AUTO</CODEGROUP><CODEGROUPX>Measurement method</CODEGROUPX>
            <CODEVALUES>
              <CODEVALUEC><CODEVALUE>00ND</CODEVALUE><CODEVALUEX>0-Inspection Not Done/not inspectable</CODEVALUEX></CODEVALUEC>
              <CODEVALUEC><CODEVALUE>01AU</CODEVALUE><CODEVALUEX>Automatic</CODEVALUEX></CODEVALUEC>
              <CODEVALUEC><CODEVALUE>01MA</CODEVALUE><CODEVALUEX>Manual</CODEVALUEX></CODEVALUEC>
            </CODEVALUES>
        </CODEGROUPC>
      </CODEGROUPS>
</MASTERDATA>'
if object_id('tempdb..#tmpXmlData') is not null Begin
    drop table #tmpXmlData
End
create table #tmpXmlData (
    ExistingCodeGroupId int,
    Plant varchar(100),
    CodeGroup varchar(100),
    Description varchar(100),

    CodeValue varchar(100),
    CodeValueDescription varchar(100)
    )
insert into #tmpXmlData
SELECT gc.CodeGroupId
      ,@data.value('(/MASTERDATA/@plant)[1]','varchar(100)') AS Plant
      ,cGr.value('(CODEGROUP/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS CodeGroup
      ,cGr.value('(CODEGROUPX/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS Description
      ,cVl.value('(CODEVALUE/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS CodeValue
      ,cVl.value('(CODEVALUEX/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS CodeValueDescription

FROM @data.nodes('/MASTERDATA/CODEGROUPS/CODEGROUPC') A(cGr)
OUTER APPLY cGr.nodes('CODEVALUES/CODEVALUEC') B(cVl)
left join CodeGroup gc
on gc.Masterdata_plant = @data.value('(/MASTERDATA/@plant)[1]','varchar(100)')
and gc.Code = cGr.value('(CODEGROUP/text())[1]','varchar(100)')

SELECT * FROM #tmpXmlData;
if object_id('tempdb..#IDs') is not null Begin
    drop table #IDs
end
    create table #IDs(
    CodeGroupID int,
    Plant varchar(100),
    Code varchar(100),
    Description varchar(100)
    )
    go
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CodeGroup] ON #IDs
(
    [Plant] ASC,
    [Code] ASC
)
;MERGE INTO dbo.CodeGroup AS TARGET
USING
(
select ExistingCodeGroupId, Plant, CodeGroup,Description
from #tmpXmlData
group by ExistingCodeGroupId, Plant, CodeGroup,Description
)
AS SOURCE ON (SOURCE.ExistingCodeGroupId= TARGET.CodeGroupId)
    --Plant, and CodeGroup must have matched already in left join above.
WHEN MATCHED
    and TARGET.Description <> SOURCE.Description
    THEN UPDATE SET TARGET.Description = SOURCE.Description
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT (Masterdata_plant, Code, Description)
         VALUES (SOURCE.Plant, SOURCE.CodeGroup, SOURCE.Description)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    THEN DELETE
output inserted.*
into #IDs; --This gets us the new CodeGroupId's


    select * from #IDs

;MERGE INTO dbo.CodeValue AS TARGET
USING
(
    select CodeGroupID=coalesce(d.ExistingCodeGroupId,i.CodeGroupID), CodeValue, CodeValueDescription
    from #tmpXmlData d
    left join #IDs i
    on i.Plant = d.Plant
    and i.Code = d.CodeGroup

    group by coalesce(d.ExistingCodeGroupId,i.CodeGroupID), CodeValue, CodeValueDescription
)
AS SOURCE ON (SOURCE.CodeGroupID= TARGET.CodeGroupID
                and SOURCE.CodeValue = Target.Code)
WHEN MATCHED
    and TARGET.Description <> SOURCE.CodeValueDescription
    THEN UPDATE SET TARGET.Description = SOURCE.CodeValueDescription
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT (CodeGroupID, Code, Description)
         VALUES (SOURCE.CodeGroupID, SOURCE.CodeValue, SOURCE.CodeValueDescription)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    THEN DELETE
output inserted.*;

select * from dbo.CodeGroup
select * from dbo.CodeValue
```